# How do automation for web services using CuCumber?

Tags: cucumber

How to do automation for web services using Cu Cumber? Please guide me on  how to start it for my project on web services.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start automation testing using cucumber. Cucumber is just a BDD framework, which lets you execute test cases.

However, The most recommended option is to use ruby language with the cucumber framework. If your using ruby and if your project has rest-api's, you can use the gem called `rest-client` and `airborne`.

You can search about these, and learn how are you going to pass the request with the parameters and analyse the response and call these codes using gherkin language. All these together will constitute a framework called cucumber, which you can use to execute.

On a side note: The next time you post, please have some research already done and post what error are you facing.